# How to reduce codes with type hint (php, laravel, dynamic properties)

Tags: php, laravel

I use:
php 8, laravel 9,
controller layer -> service layer -> repository layer -> model
vscode

**OrderController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Sale;

use App\Services\Sale\OrderService;
use App\Services\Member\MemberService;
use App\Services\Catalog\ProductService;
use App\Services\Common\OptionService;
use App\Services\Localization\CountryService;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Request $request, OrderService $OrderService
        , MemberService $MemberService
        , OptionService $OptionService
        , ProductService $ProductService
        , CountryService $CountryService
        , DivisionService $DivisionService
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->OrderService = $OrderService;
        $this->MemberService = $MemberService;
        $this->ProductService = $ProductService;
        $this->OptionService = $OptionService;
        $this->CountryService = $CountryService;
        $this->DivisionService = $DivisionService;
    }
```

Now I found that vscode have underlines with "Undefined property" to all lines inside __construct(). They are called dynamic properties, because they weren't declared. And I learned that in php 9, dynamic properties is not allowed.

I have to add

```
private $request;
private $OrderService;
private $MemberService;
private $ProductService;
private $OptionService;
private $CountryService;
private $DivisionService;
```

So it becomes

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Sale;

// Part 1: use
use App\Services\Sale\OrderService;
use App\Services\Member\MemberService;
use App\Services\Catalog\ProductService;
use App\Services\Common\OptionService;
use App\Services\Localization\CountryService;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    // Part 2: declare
    private $request;
    private $OrderService;
    private $MemberService;
    private $ProductService;
    private $OptionService;
    private $CountryService;

    // Part 3: arguments
    public function __construct(Request $request, OrderService $OrderService
        , MemberService $MemberService
        , ProductService $ProductService
        , OptionService $OptionService
        , CountryService $CountryService
    )
    {
        // Part 4: set
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->OrderService = $OrderService;
        $this->MemberService = $MemberService;
        $this->ProductService = $ProductService;
        $this->OptionService = $OptionService;
        $this->CountryService = $CountryService;
    }
```

Part 1, we have to know where the classes are, ok. But I think part 2,3,4 almost the same. Is there any other way to reduce the codes?

Comment: `2 and 3` are not the same. Yes, you declare all values there but you can also define an access level `(private, public, etc)`. Part 3 is how you get the variables, but with the exception of `Request $request` I don't see the need to pass all the services as params in the constructer instead of just initializing them in part 4 without them being passed as parameters to your constructor.

Comment: Pass the params is different with initializing inside. For example, ProductService(ProductRepository $ProductRepository ... ... ) has the same structure with ProductController.  If initializing inside ProductController's __construct, then I have to also pass $ProductRepository as params.  ProductController:  $this->ProductService = new ProductService($SomeRepository). So I use type hint. This is what type hint does, isn't it?

Comment: @ronrun, to clear up the confusion here. While the type hint enables it, the Laravel Service container makes it happen through Dependency Injection. You can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container - if you were to use another PHP framework, it would not automatically work. The accepted answer below does work regardless of the framework, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 8 offers [constructor property promotion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion).

Just pasting the code below should work.

```
public function __construct(
    private Request $request, 
    private OrderService $OrderService,
    private MemberService $MemberService,
    private ProductService $ProductService,
    private OptionService $OptionService,
    private CountryService $CountryService,
    ) {}
```

Comment: It seems works!! Thank you. Later if no problems, I'll mark your answer.